# Bootstrap based webpage is not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I recently built a "responsive" webpage with **bootstrap**. The weird thing is when I check the different resolutions on my computer I can see that the page is truly responsive. When I checked it on my phone the **text was small**, the **navigation menu didn't change to its responsive mode**. When i minimize the browser window to the resolution of a phone it works perfectly.
(By the way i checked it on my Gallaxy S3 and WP8, I'm pretty sure the problem is in all mobile devices). I came a cross something called **viewport**, but its quite hard to understand how to use it.

**Can someone help with this problem? How can i fix it?**

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hello. Show. The. Code.

Comment: Take a look at the basic template on the bootstrap documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template. Make sure you have the fundamentals in place.

Comment: Note that WP8 requires an additional hack because IE is (unsurprisingly) buggy: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your html:

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```